# Can I combine successive Sugar.js calls to Array.map?

Tags: javascript, sugar.js

For example, if my array is multi-dimensional:

```
var myArray = [
    {
        key1: {
            key2: 1,
            ...
        },
        ...
    },
    {
        key1: {
            key2: 2,
            ...
        },
        ...
    }
];

myArray.map('key1').sum('key2');
= 3
```

This could also be

```
myArray.map('key1').map('key2').sum();
```

but is there a way to combine them into one call to `map`?

Comment: But those are not arrays...What are you trying to do?

Comment: Thanks. I've clarified the code example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When map takes a string it is effectively a shortcut for [pluck](http://underscorejs.org/#pluck).

As [described in the Sugar documentation](http://sugarjs.com/api/Array/map), map can more traditionally take a function as well:

> **map( map , scope )**
>
> Maps the array to another array containing the values that are the result of calling map on each element. scope is
> the this object. In addition to providing this method for browsers
> that don't support it natively, this enhanced method also directly
> accepts a string, which is a shortcut for a function that gets that
> property (or invokes a function) on each element.
>
> Returns: Array

**Therefore:**

```
myArray.map(function(x) { return x.key1.key2; }).sum()
```

Comment: Yes, this is one call to map, but the purpose is that the overall solution would be shorter (and simpler), not longer.